# Problems with Web Service Data Source in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: java, web-services, crystal-reports, enterprise, weblogic-10.x

I'm trying to hook up my SOAP webservice to be used as a crystal reports data service and I'm running into some problems.  I follow the wizard and after I enter my WSDL URL and my credentials, I go on to the final page.  On this page, the drop down boxes are empty.  I manually enter the service name, port and method, and then hit finish and I get the following error:

WSDLException (at /definitions/types/xsd:schema):
faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error occurred trying to resolve schema
 referenced at
 '
 relative to 'URL': java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP respose
 code: 401: for url

My schema definition is in a separate file that is pointed to in my wsdl by a  tag.

I think the problem is this:  Crystal Reports successfully authenticates against my server and retrieves the wsdl, then tries to load the schema but doesn't authenticate against the server when does, so I end up with the 401 error.

My webservice is a JAXWS deployed as a war file under BEA Weblogic 10.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this same problem....What I did to work around this is enable authentication only on POST requests (the actual web service calls).  So retrieving the WSDL does not require any authentication.

I did this by adding this line in my web.xml file:

```
<http-method>POST</http-method>
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use an SQL View for ALL your reporting needs?